# C++ templates: Returning list::iterator

Tags: c++, templates

How can I make the following code work? During compilation I get an error telling me that the `searchForResource` function has no return type.

```
template<class T>
class ResourceManager
{
  private:
    struct ResourceWrapper;
    std::list<ResourceWrapper*> resources_; // This compiles fine

    std::list<ResourceWrapper*>::iterator  // Error occurs here
        searchForResource(const std::string& file);
};
```

Also, is this how I would define the `searchForResource` function?

```
template<class t>
std::list<typename ResourceManager<T>::ResourceWrapper*>::iterator
    ResourceManager<T>::searchForResource(const std::string& file)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::list<ResourceWrapper*>::iterator` is hard for the compiler to understand. Prefix it with **`typename`** in both the implementation and the declaration to let the compiler know that it's a type.

Like so:

```
typename std::list<ResourceWrapper*>::iterator searchForResource(const std::string& file);
```

Comment: Implementation is definition. Apply this to the *declaration* and definition.

Comment: what do you mean "hard"? it either can or can't. Also, what's "hard" in std::list::iterator? Your solution may be right, but the explanation is of little help

Comment: It depends on when the compiler parses the text.  If the
compiler doesn't parse any of the template text, treating it as
a glorified macro, then it has no problem knowing that
`std::list<ResourseWrapper*>::iterator` is the name of a type.
If the compiler parses the text when it reads the template, and
not just when it instantiates it, it has to know which symbols
represent typenames and templates; you can't parse C++
otherwise.  If the name isn't dependent, it can look it up in
scope; in this case, the name is dependent, so you have to tell
the compiler that it is a typename.

Comment: James covered it pretty well. I found this explanation helpful too: http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation

Comment: @Slavik81: The compiler cannot figure it out upfront. The `typename` is required by the standard, as `ResourceWrapper` is a dependent identifier. Note that the full name is `ResourceManager<T>::ResourceWrapper`, that `T` in the name means that there could be an specialization of `std::list` for a particular `T` that could change the meaning of `std::list<ResourceWrapper>` to contain a non-type member `iterator`

Comment: Right. I'm not sure precisely why waiting until instantiation was abandoned, but from my understanding it was because there were other issues that would be difficult to resolve otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class T>
class ResourceManager
{
  private:
    struct ResourceWrapper;
    std::list<ResourceWrapper*> resources_;

//      | typename lost here
//      V
    typename std::list<ResourceWrapper*>::iterator
        searchForResource(const std::string& file);
};

template<class T>
//  | typename lost here                    asterisk lost here | 
//  V                                                          V 
typename std::list<typename ResourceManager<T>::ResourceWrapper*>::iterator
    ResourceManager<T>::searchForResource(const std::string& file)
{
   return ...   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a rule of thumb to avoid such compilation errors.

*Whenever you are **declaring a variable or function**, with a template followed by scope resolution operator `::` then always put a keyword `typename` in front of the definition.*

For example,

```
MyNameSpace::MyClass<T> x; // Ok; because template is NOT followed by scope resolution
MyNameSpace::MyClass<T>::MyType x; // Error; MyType can be a variable or a type; so put typename ahead
```

Same thing is applicable to function declaration also.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing a `typename` keyword.

Comment: Doing `std::list<typename ResourceWrapper*>::iterator ...` gives the same error.

Comment: You put the typename in the wrong place. See slavik's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ResourceWrapper` is a dependent name <sup>*</sup>(it's definition depends on the type argument `T`), and that makes `std::list< ResourceWrapper * >` a dependent type name. Templates are checked in two passes, during the first pass, correctness of the template *without* actual type substitution is checked. Now when you type `std::list< ResourceWrapper* >::iterator` the compiler cannot know upfront that `iterator` is in fact a type and not an static attribute or member of the class `std::list< ResourceWrapper* >` because of the type being dependent and the `T` not yet being substituted.

You have to hint the compiler as to inform it that the `iterator` is indeed a type by using the `typename` keyword, as others have already mentioned before:

```
typename std::list< ResourceWrapper* >::iterator
```

Without seeing the rest of the code, I cannot say, but it seems as if `ResourceWrapper` should actually not be a dependent type on `T`. If it is in fact non-dependent, you should move the type outside of the class template. in that case, the `typename` will no longer be required:

```
struct ResourceWrapper;
template <typename T>
class ResourceManager {
   std::list<ResourceWrapper*>::iterator searchForResource(const std::string& file);
...
```

Because it is defined outside of the template there is a single definition for all possible instantiations of the `ResourceManager` template, now `ResourceWrapper` is no longer dependent on `T`, and `typename` is no longer needed (nor correct).

<sup>*</sup> Why is `ResourceWrapper` dependent and how could this affect the code.

The reason that `ResourceWrapper` is dependent on the type `T` is easier seen by discussing the fully qualified name: `::ResourceManager<T>::ResourceWrapper`. The `T` is part of the type, and as such `T` affects the actual definition of `ResourceWrapper`. This is somehow a contrived example in that you can arguably say that if the compiler is parsing this particular template, then it must know that `ResourceWrapper` is a type, and thus that `std::list< ResourceWrapper*>::iterator` is a type... and here is the problem. There is no particular reason not to have an specialization of the `std::list` template for a particular instantiation of `ResourceManager`:

```
namespace std { // you should in general not add things to the std namespace!
                // but the implementation can
template <>
struct list< ResourceManager<int>::ResourceWrapper > {
   static const int iterator = 5;
...
};
}
```

Again, contrived, but the compiler cannot possibly know upfront while parsing the template that such an specialization will not be present before you actually instantiate the template with a particular type.

Answer (score 0):

you have forward declaration of ResourceWrapper struct which is good enough for the line that compiles fine, but you are getting the error because at that point compiler needs full type declaration for ResourceWrapper struct.  (possibly your answer, this code actually compiles fine with VS2008)